# React Native JS: Expected a component class, got [object Object]

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an error and really don't know why. It's a verry simple code juste for test react native, wanted to create a class who call an other class with  and une a button to increment quantity :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class Apprentissage1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcolm bitch
        </Text>
        <Product name="Product 1"/>
        <Product name="Product 2"/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Product extends Component {

    constructor(props) {                                //Constructeur
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            quantity: 0
        };
    }


  addToCart(){
    this.setState({
      quantity: this.state.quantity + 1
    })
  }
  render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <h2>{this.props.name}</h2>
          <p>Quantity: {this.state.quantity}</p>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.addToCart.bind(this)}>
          Add To cart
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Apprentissage1', () => Apprentissage1);
```

Thank's for your help :)

Comment: You cant render HTML in a react-native app without using the WebView component... This error is related to the render function in your Product component

Comment: try removing ```export default``` from ```export default class Apprentissage1 extends Component {``` and replace html components with react native components such as ```<Text>```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `<h2>` and `<p>` tags with React Native `<View>` component.

You cannot use DOM elements in your React Native application.

Comment: Good catch. That would definitely cause a problem as well.

Comment: Thank, it work ! I already had an other error whith the <TouchableHighlight> element which must have a child element (I haded <Text> inside)

Answer (score 1):

That's because  you are using a non components elements like h2, p which are html elements and not react-native components.
Correct component to use for this is `Text` 
then use Text for both h2 and p. just manipulate its fontSize to suit your needs.

```
<Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>{this.props.name}</Text>
<Text style={{ fontSize: 12}}>Quantity: {this.state.quantity}</Text>
```

Also `ToucheableHighlight` should contain a single element not a string.

```
  <ToucheableHighlight
    onPress={this.addToCart.bind(this)}
  >
    <Text>
        Add to Cart
     </Text>
   </ToucheableHighlight>
```

Comment: Thank, it work ! I already had an other error whith the <TouchableHighlight> element which must have a child element (I haded <Text> inside)

Comment: @BlackStef Great! Edited my answer to include that if someone needs it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the error is getting triggered, but your `onPress` for the `TouchableHighlight` can just be `() => { this.setState({quantity: this.state.quantity + 1}) }` instead of `this.bind.addToCart(this)`.

Answer (score -1):

Separate the Product class to a new file then import it. React Native does not really like having multiple components in the same file.

Also how did you initialize the project? what is the error message?

Comment: This is incorrect. React Native has no problem with having multiple components in the same file so long as there is only one default being exported.